# Generic Type inference has a strange behavior

Tags: c#, .net

I hope someone can explain me a strange behavior from the C# type inference system, when attempting to "partially apply" functions.

Assume I have following code:

```cs
int Add(int a, int b) => a + b;
```

Why can the inference system not infer the type of X if I declare it like following:

```cs
var add1 = (x) => Add(1, x); // does not work: CS8917: The delegate type could not be inferred.
var add1 = (int x) => Add(1, x); // does work

var add_1 = PartiallyApply(Add, 1);


Func<T1, T2, TResult> PartiallyApply<T1, T2, TResult>(Func<T1, T2, TResult> func, T1 param) {
  return (p2) => func(param, p2);
}
```

The second version makes sense, if the inference system runs from top to bottom, so you have to declare everything before you use it.
The type inference system of F# goes the other way around, and checks the usage of the function to infer the used types.

I would really appreciate some ideas and if I can overcome this issue somehow using !inline! declarations.
I know there are other ways to overcome this issue, by using explicit typing but that's not the route I want to take.

Thanks in adavance everyone

Comment: Because `x` could be something that has an implicit cast to `int` and still work.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce. Both lines give an error](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLQGMD2A3KCCWUAdjKkvAkcgDQAmIA1AD4ACATAIwCwAULggAIotWhwEBeAQAoAHgEoJAPgEBBEVI7UB8gNy9+QkWwnT8JbQvHK1tDVt28zMVeqdCtb4JeVQBDAcA6QA==)

Comment: The code posted has nothing to do with generics, and generic types.

Comment: @JAlex Good point.. I missed that part ^^ Updated the question

Comment: @Sweeper actually this type of type inference has just been introduced with C# 10

Comment: @juharr Actually I do not understand this response. If it would have an implicit cast in place, the compile should use it otherwise would be forced to use the explicit cast. On the other hand, the function prototype enforces int type, so variable X must be of type, there is no other choice available.

If this would not work, this shouldn't be possible in F# either...

Comment: @PascalKohl For instance this would work `var add1 = (short x) => Add(1, x);` because there's an implicit cast from `short` to `int` and now how is the compiler suppose to know if you meant `x` to be `int` or `short`?  Basically it's not going to guess if there is any possibility of ambiguity.

Comment: Besides quipping about the "strange" behavior is there a specific problem you are trying to work through? What is your intent, and why isn't declaring a type a viable solution?

Answer (score 0):

You must explicitly give the type of X , for this function to work properly !